# Create export wizard in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, wizard

I want to create an Export Function for my plug-in.
I already created custom actions for that (in the context menu)

I have 3 folders and I just want to copy one folder to a destination (which the user should be able to select).

Do I need to create a wizard for that or are there simple ways?
Does a wizard already exist which I can use?
A nice tutorial for that would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the extension point org.eclipse.ui.exportWizards to implement your functionality

Check this http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_exportWizards.html&resultof=%22eclipse%22%20%22eclips%22%20%22export%22%20%22wizard%22%20

In the class attribute you can provide your own implementation of export wizard functionality.

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: I dont really know how to implement that class which should implement the IExportWizard. that is the point where I am hanging

Comment: The class will be your actual implementation of your functionality.I think this one "I have 3 Folders and I just want to copy one folder to a destination (which the user should be able to select)."